# Representing a small battery powered motor

Tags: java, driver, battery

I have an application that I am working on and I want to create a class that would represent a small battery powered motor that has these methods:

- constructor: DCMotor(Battery bat1, Battery bat2)
- `drain()` - drains the battery by the constant amount
- `runTIme()` - shows how long the motor has been running and gives a warning when the battery drops to 90% capacity
- `start()` - starts the motor and displays the running time and remaining capacity of the battery. (If the motor can not be started be cause the capacity is to low a warning message is displayed)
- `stop()` - stops the motor

The battery capacity for the motor is the sum of the capacity for each battery, in this case two batteries.  When the motor is started, the motor will continually display its status until it is stopped or the battery capacity is too low.

What I have so far I know is pretty low-level but I can't figure out how to code it correctly and get the results I want.

Here is my code:

```
public class DCMotor {

double capacity = 7000.0;

public DCMotor(Battery bat1, Battery bat2)
{
     bat1 = new Battery(3500.0);
     bat2 = new Battery(3500.0);
}

public void drain() //drains the battery by a constant amount
{
    do
    {
        capacity -= 50.0;
    }while(capacity <= 7000.0 && capacity > 0);

}

public String runTime() //shows how long the battery has been running
{
    if (capacity == 6300.0)
        System.out.println("90% battery remaining.");
    return "90% battery remaining.";
}

public void start() //starts the motor and displays the running time and available capacity
{
    start();
    //try{ Thread.sleep(1000);} catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
    System.out.println("Remaining Capacity: " + capacity);
}

public void stop() //stops the motor
{
    stop();
}
}
```

Comment: "I can't figure out how to code it correctly and get the results I want." This is *extremely* vague. I have absolutely no clue what problem you are having nor the results you want, and the code doesn't help at all because I don't know what's wrong with it. It's like calling tech support, saying "I have a problem", and expecting help. Well, that's rather unfortunate, but we can't help you unless you give more details because that "problem" could be anything. Can you add more details?

Comment: in the runTime() method i want it to show how long the battery has been running. And if and when it gets to 90% remaining, displays a warning. and in the start() method, I want it to start the battery and display the running time and remaining capacity of the battery.

Comment: OK. What's wrong with what you have now, and what alternatives have you tried/looked up? Those sound like simple enough requirements that you could at least *try* to code something.

Comment: Why do you have a constructor that takes 2 batteries but constructs new once inside the constructor?! Also the motor knowns everything about the capacity of the batteries whereas that should be the responsibility of the battery not the motor.

Comment: You might also benefit by taking a step back from your computer, taking out a pencil and piece of paper, and taking some time to figure out how *you*, as a human, would do those requirements. If you were the motor, and someone asked you "What is the runtime?", what steps would you carry out to figure that out? How might you convert that to pseudocode? And how might you convert that to Java code? It might also help to pretend that you're giving those instructions to someone who takes things a little too literally.

Comment: This is purely a math problem.  Work it out on paper first.